# AWK: How to remove a column deliminated by mixed delimeters?

Tags: awk, delimiter, mixed

I have a table with 100,000 rows. The format is like this:

```
abc '\t' gi| a b c  d e
```

column abc is separated by tab while other columns are separated by space.I want to remove the column 'gi|' and keep all other columns. I tried use tab or | as my delimiter but it didn't work well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use awk's `sub` function.

```
awk '{sub(/.*/,"",$2)}1' file
```

OR

Just assign an empty value to the column 2 variable.

```
awk '{$2=""}1' file
```

Comment: This fails to address the delimiter issue.

Comment: @tripleee all lines are in the same format. So why we care about tabs or spaces?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was in wrong directory. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply ignore the fields?

```
sed 's/\t[^\t ]* /\t/' file
```

will remove the text after the first tab up to space.